# Excel sumifs #value when closing excel file

Tags: excel, sumifs, sumproduct

I have used the formula sumifs in order to calculate the sum of values in a column ranging between, e.g., 100 and 1000, located in a different workbook. The problem is that when I close that excel workbook the formula in my first excel file doesn't work anymore and #value appears. I would like to find an alternative formula/solution to this, and I have already looked online, but I don't seem to be able to find a proper solution. For instance, I could use sumproduct, but as a result I only get a count of the values satisfying the conditions and not the sum of them. Could you help me?
Thanks.
Giulio

Comment: You could set it up with powerquery and then you would be able to refresh it with the refresh button

Answer (score 1):

There are a few functions which do not work when the source data file is closed.  They are:

`SUMIF(), COUNTIF(), AVERAGEIF(), OFFSET(), INDIRECT(), GETPIVOTDATA(), SUMIFS(), COUNTIFS(), AVERAGEIFS().`

You will have to write alternative formulas in those cells or have the source data in the file that is doing the calculation